# MySQL: group by hour AND by other distinct fields

Tags: mysql, group-by, nested, sql-timestamp

I have a 'logs' table, in which search results' counters are stored, as well the search query and the user who searched for it.

My goal is to display results grouped by hour, but I'm having some issues when using GROUP BY because I'm losing the distinct users / queries in the process.

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/484c01/7

As you can see, results are being count according to their results no. but the output is not correct. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't want, at the same time, _group_ results by hour AND get detailed data of multiple records which participate to the group! Simply said, if you want this grouping, you must suppress `*,` from the `SELECT` clause. On the other hand you might want to get detailed records, not grouped but _ordered_ by hour, then use the returned data to aggregate `results` while printing detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are data size limits on what can be returned by the following method, but if you want to preserve distinct row values of non-grouped-by-columns when doing a `GROUP BY`, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` MySQL function which will combine each row's value into one row separated by something like commas.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for usage examples.

IMPORTANT: be sure to read the documentation's note on `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` in the link provided above.